# How to stop AWS services in Organization Unit after exceeded AWS Budget

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-organizations

I've been trying to achieve with AWS Budget after it's exceeded to stop all the active services to stop in the AWS Organization Unit.

Is it possible to be done with AWS Budget?
Is there another way of stopping the services in AWS Organization Unit

I've tried with Custom AWS Budget to Attach Action but it appears that we can only specify certain EC2 or RDS instances to stop.

Example:
[image: example]

Comment: No, not directly. It supports EC2 and RDS, from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/budgets-controls.html), plus some IAM role modifications. For arbitrary actions, you can configure an Amazon SNS topic for notifications and tie that to a custom Lambda function that can do whatever you want.

Comment: Additionally, there are services that have no real definition of "stop", like S3, that can incur ongoing costs and the only way to stop those ongoing costs involve destruction of data and/or additional costs to remove resources.

Comment: Or one more complexity: lambda - no running cost but a new invocation incurs a cost. Only option to prevent it: delete the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in multiple ways.

**Option 1**:
Send budget exceed alert to SNS topic --> Use the same SNS topic as an event source for a Lambda function --> Write a lambda function using any SDK (example: [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html)) to stop/delete most commonly used services in your OU

**Option 2**:
Instead of using AWS Budgets, you can use the [Cloudwatch Billing alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) --> Use [Cloudwatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-eventbridge.html) to trigger the Lambda function when there is a change in state of Cloudwatch Billing alarm.

You will have to then review how each services are priced. Based on that, you can decide if you have to stop the resources or delete them to stop incurring further charges.

Comment: can you provide an example or blog post from somewhere

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to locate something similar online. This is just a solution I came up given the use case. Please do try to implement and reach out to me here if you come across any errors.